How to prototype an LLM / a chatbot?
I am currently doing a UX research project about a potential LLM.
As a UX Designer, I am used to creating prototypes (e.g. in Figma) in order to evaluate the visual concept before it is going into development.
But with an LLM or a chatbot, the main interaction is conversational, which I do not see how this can be prototyped. Do you have any experience in how to do early evaluations of an LLM, without having to develop one yourself?
I was already thinking about creating a custom GPT in ChatGPT, but this is highly unacademic due to data privacy issues. And building one on my own with open source models like Llama will take too much time.

Great question. Firstly,
 Do not waste time testing the UI

There's huge amount of research done by popular conversation apps and the user flows they come up with are to be reused. I don't think there would be high returns if you reinvent the wheel.
Everyone has used a conversation app in today's world already. Be it with chatbot or be it with a friend or family.

Like you identified, the main interaction to be tested is the CONVERSATION ITSELF. Like: • How does the user react to what the LLM replies. • How does the user then reply to that. • Do they like the conversational tone. • Did they manage to get what they want with short time. etc.. (more to be defined by checking what your product values are)
 Focus on testing the conversational experience itself 
I mean it.
But, how do we do that without spending huge amount of time training the model? (Also spending so much effort in advance defeats the purpose of testing prototypes itself.)
I suggest this hack. A bit unconventional but it hits the objective in least effort.

Use an unfamiliar messaging app as your base of prototype. 

Tester types in and sends their question.

You, sitting in another room (pretending to be the ai in the shadows), replies to the user.

You will mimic the tone and way that the LLM that you are building WOULD reply. You know this as you know how the LLM is gonna be trained and its just hugely depenant on your product values.


P.S: Using an unfamiliar app is important to have least bias.
From that you will be able to validate the feelings and responses from real users. In the most cost effective way!
This gives you a way to test how the user interacts with you future fully developed LLM.

This also gives you full flexibility on trying out different conversational styles of the ai.
You may manage the user expection on the slower reply than an ai by letting them know that this is a prototype and it would be 10x faster in the future.
Some tips are for yourself to be pre-prepared with a set of replies to common questions that the user might ask.

But yes, this hacky validation technique for LLM would fail if you are building a bot that always has to reply in a very long form - as the person typing cannot be fast enough!

I like this different take on the prototyping concept! Very interesting! and seems like a huge cost saver.

I really like this approach, provides a different angle and flexibility. I will definitely try something like this out and see, how it goes. +1

Awesome! @MichaelSchmidt. Let me know your learnings too. Happy to help.

You can run javascript and HTML objects inside Axure RP. I've hooked one up to both CharGPT and Ollama. However, it's fairly easy to just add a bootstrap HTML front end and skin it from there. But if you have other content the push it via an iframe and design around it.
However, consider how your model is set up. You can just use a GPT for the NLP interface and get it to talk to your actual processing object (e.g. a RAG).
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2023/10/how-to-build-llm-apps-using-vector-database/

I designed a chatbot ones for booking personal assistants and for prototyping we used predefined conversation and options like the type of booking, time selection, and uploading and also created a flowmap for understanding conditional scenarios.
So in Figma, there is no option to prototype the user input but generally in the chatbot things to note are how to handle very long text, editing, deleting messages, and if there are different selections check conditions.

When working with conversational interfaces, especially when dealing with LLMs (Large Language Models), the traditional approach of prototyping in tools like Figma might seem challenging at first. However, Figma can still be a powerful tool for this purpose.
Prototyping Conversational Interactions in Figma
You can prototype the conversational flow by predefining the interaction paths and creating sample conversations. Here's how you can approach it:
Define the Flow: Start by mapping out the key interaction points of your conversation. Identify decision points, user inputs, and potential responses from the LLM.
Create Sample Conversations: Design these interactions as separate frames or screens in Figma. You can use components to represent different states of the conversation (e.g., user input, LLM response).
Link Screens: Once your conversations are designed, use Figma’s prototyping feature to link these screens together. This will allow you to simulate the flow of conversation as if it were happening in real-time.
Interactive Components: Leverage Figma’s interactive components to create more dynamic prototypes. For example, buttons that simulate user choices or input fields that change the state of the conversation.
Quick POC Example
I recently created a simple prototype for a conversational interaction in Figma, which took me about 20 minutes. While there’s always room for improvement, it’s a good starting point for a proof of concept (POC). This method allows for quick iteration and can be very effective in early-stage evaluations.


Add a mask where the conversation is going to appear. You may consider creating a component that mimics 'typing...' in between every reply. User input is not possible but this planned story and prototyping does work well.
